# Accessing an object(1) inside an object(2) that was created in the first object(1)

Tags: python, object, oop

After creating an object(second) inside an object(first) i want to get access to the first object. Is this possible without giving the second object the first object as an attribute?

In the code below i have access to my first object. I'm just curious if there is a better way to achive something similiar, without pass on my first object to my second object.

```
class first():
    def __init__(self,v):
        
        self.a = v
        self.b = second(self)
        
        
class second():
    def __init__(self, first):
        
        
        
        self.changefirst(first)
        
    def changefirst(self,first):
        first.a = 5
        
        
x = first(3)
print(x.a)
```

Output:
5

Comment: No; objects don't know anything about what references them, so if you want an instance of `second` to know about the instance of `first`, you need to provide that reference explicitly.

Comment: No, there's no better way.

Comment: The same `second` object could be referenced by multiple objects.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, you probably want to *save* the reference to `first` rather than use it and discard it. `self.first = first`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method within `first`, like this :

```py
class first:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.a = v
        self.b = second()
        self.update_a(5)

    def update_a(self, val):
        self.a = val


class second:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


x = first(3)
print(x.a)
```

5

Now, if you want to trigger the update of `a` from `b`, you have to pass `self` since the attributes are attached to it.

Another way :

```py
class first:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.a = v
        self.b = second(self)

    def update_a(self, val):
        self.a = val


class second:
    def __init__(self, that):
        that.update_a(5)
```